# Console.error does not print string in correct location

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

This has me puzzled. I can't figure out why it outputs the text in this fashion with the `<>` at the end

```
function foo(){
 console.error('Trying to phase out <' + arguments.callee.name + '>');
 //output
 Trying to phase out foo <>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `arguments.callee.name` is `null`